# my charmed kubernetes stuck in wait for 3 kube-system

Tags: juju, maas, kubernetes

I am just installed charmed kubernetes with juju on top of maas
which my maas is built on kvm and when my charmed complete the master nods stuck in wait for 3 kube-system